# All even order graphs with $\Delta\ge\frac{n}{2}$ is Class 1

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings, matching-theory

Are all even order graphs with maximum degree $\ge\frac{|V(G)|}{2}$ Class 1(edge-colorable(chromatic index) with $\delta(G)$ colors)? Here, $|V(G)|$ detnotes the number of vertices in the graph.

I think yes, because, by Erdos-Posa theorem on the number of maximal disjoint circuits in a graph, we have that any graph has a matching of size at least $min(\delta(G), \frac{|V(G)|}{2})$. Now, consider a regular graph of degree $\delta(G)$. Then, by the Erdós-Pósa theorem, it will have a perfect matching(as $\delta(G)\ge\frac{|V(G)|}{2})$, in fact, $\delta$ perfect matchings(I think), because each independence-induced subgraph(graph formed by deleting a set of independent vertices from the graph) would also have a 1-factor and thus, the whole graph should be 1-factorizable, that is must be Class 1. Thus, any graph with maximum degree at least $\delta(G)$ should be Class 1. Any hints. Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Does [it](https://hog.grinvin.org/ViewGraphInfo.action?id=33662) serves as a counterexample?

Comment: @Bullet51 thanks, yes it should serve as a counterexample. But, are there vertex transitive counterexamples?

Comment: [Possibly not.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.4178)

Comment: I thought Class1 meant edge colorable with $\Delta(G)$ colors? Why would any non-regular graph be edge colorable with $\delta(G)$ colors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [counterexample](https://hog.grinvin.org/ViewGraphInfo.action?id=33662) can be found by adjointing a tree to a class-2 graph with some edges removed.

Comment: so this implies that every induced subgraph of a class 1 graph is class 1, that is the edge coloring class is a hereditary one, right

Comment: No. Consider [K5+pendant](https://hog.grinvin.org/ViewGraphInfo.action?id=220) and $K_5$.

Comment: Ok is at least every even induced subgraph  hereditary? or, say independece induced(formed by deleting independent set of vertices) even subgraph?

Comment: No. Change the K5 in the previous construction into Petersen. P.S. Comments are not suitable for chatting.

Comment: got it! But, I believe, every induced even subgraph of a Class 1 graph has $\Delta-2$ 1-factors. Any counterexample to this? Sorry, if it is too chatty, but bear just this one time!